# Setting contentSizeForViewInPopover property of UINavigationController seems to fail

Tags: ios, properties, uinavigationcontroller, popover, contentsize

As the following code seems to show, setting the contentSizeForViewInPopover property of a UINavigationController object seems to fail.  Is this behavior as expected?  Am I making some error?  Thanks.

(Using XCode 4.6, Mac OS X v 10.7.5)

```
// Make a plain view controller.
UIViewController * root = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

// Make a navigation controller whose root view is the plain
// view controller from above.
UINavigationController * nav =
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: root];

// Set the content size for popover to 100 x 100.
nav.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(100, 100);

// Print out the property that we just set.
NSLog (@"size = (%f, %f)",
       nav.contentSizeForViewInPopover.width,
       nav.contentSizeForViewInPopover.height);

// It prints: size = (320.000000, 1144.000000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to change `contentSizeForViewInPopover` of the navigation controller. Change it on `root` instead. `UINavigationController` calculates its size automatically from its current controller by adding the size required for its navigation bar.

Comment: Thank you Sulthan.  With more experiment, I discovered that the navigation controller gets its contentSizeForViewInPopover from whatever is on top of the navigation stack, as you say.